# How to make videos autoplay in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, autoplay

Chrome's updated it auto play policy which block user from autoplaying the video. I am having signage board where it is most important feature for my application. Is there any way I can autoplay the video? Please let us know if any solution or workaround is available. As per google document you can run video with sound in PWA app. I have tried that as will but unable to play the video. Thank you in advance. (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#new-behaviors)

I have also referred multiple stack overflow question but haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility if you mute your video by default autoplay is allowed and maybe unmute it onTouchstart:

```
<video autoplay muted> </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that Chrome blocks autoplay on videos, it's just not allowing to play it without prior user interaction with the page (click, tap, etc.) and when it's not muted, so one of those two conditions has to be fulfilled in order to autoplay.

Comment: Thank you for your response but the thing is I am trying one signage board in which video is main component and we need to play it without user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

There are developer switches that you can use to force allowing autoplay, see [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes):

```
chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

Comment: Hi @zero298 I have tried below solution but it is not working for me.